# Communication between user-service and auth-service in microservice architecture

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, microservices, restful-authentication

**Scenario:**

This is my login scenario for my microservice application:

1. The user enters his phone number
2. A verification code will be sent
3. The user must send the received code to verify it
4. The user must enter his password
5. A JWT Token will be received

**REST Implementation**

For implementing the given scenario, I've created three services: auth, sms, and user. From my point of view, I think it's better to handle requests for sending verification code and generating JWT token from user-service. Here is the detail of my implementation:

- User calls `POST /user/sms` to send his phone number to the **user-service**. Inside that, a request will be made to the **sms-service** to send the verification code.
- Then user calls `POST /user/verify` to verify the code, again this request will be handled inside the **user-service**. If the code is valid, user-service will generate a temporary token and pass it to the header response (assume that the user is already registered into the system)
- Now the user passes his password with the temporary token via `POST /user/password`. If the credentials are valid, **user-service** will call **auth-service** to get a JWT token and append it to the response header of `POST /user/password`.

**Question**

Are there right communications between user<->auth and user<->sms services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the way you have drawn boundaries between services is not a problem in any case.
There are some **pros and cons** that I can see here

Having separate SMS-Service it gives you possibility to use it even in other scenarios like sending other type of notification to user, it makes it easy if you want to change SMS provider, but this service should be all stand alone(using a message broker for comunication).

User service is totally fine, but you should be aware of that each new HTTP call to another service creates "Latency"(you should take that into consideration), like in this case when a new http call is made for releasing a TOKEN.

When you have a service calling another service than you introduce coupling. In my point of view if you don't use any third party tool for handling Tokens than I think you should have both the Token handling and User within the same microservice, I think that this way you have a better Bounded-Context and it is more easy to run joins since these data will be within a same database.

In case you use third party tool for handling Tokens than it is OK to have it in different Service since in that way you will create abstraction and will be easily to change tool in future.

**Heads-up**

Make sure that each Microservice has it own database and you don't access any other database directly outside of the Context that service belong to.

Comment: What about adding an orchestrator for handling these things?